# How to predict customer churn by a certain date?

Tags: machine-learning, churn, pycaret

I have a dataset of inactive users for the last 365 days, with columns:

1. When subscribed (e.g. 10.10.2022)
2. When unsubscribed (e.g. 12.10.2022)

and client info

I also have a set of data about active users:

1. When subscribed

and client info.

Question: How can I get a prediction of whether a certain user will unsubscribe within a month from now?  What should be the logic of my actions in this case?

I tried to calculate an unsubscribe date using linear regression and got a result, for example, 03.15.2023. But in that case, I can't understand with what probability the person will unsubscribe in a month, namely on 01.12.2023

I will be grateful for any hints.
Thanks

Comment: You will first need to preprocess your data by converting the "when subscribed" and "when unsubscribed" columns to a numerical format that the model can understand.

Comment: @Vic Yes, I converted them to the Unix timestamp format. There is no problem with that. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: You may be interested in [survival analysis](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Analysis%20intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is better framed as [survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis), the expected time duration until an event occurs. The goal would be to fit a model that predicts the probability of churn as a function of the number of days thus far and other features.